# Acting as Batman vs acting as Bruce Wayne

Tags: dc, the-batman

Throught the "The Batman" movie, I perceived hints that the movie would have the moral that Bruce Wayne ought to do good as himself, rather than trying to fight crime as Batman.

> Early on, Bruce brushes off a meeting with his accountants. Later we learn that, devoid of oversight, the Wayne Foundation was highjacked by organized crime (and in fact, that the existence of so much organized crime in Gotham is because of the temptation offered by this money). Moreover, the catalyst for the Riddler to embark on his murder spree was precisely that he realised this.

But then the ending was a bog-standard "Hero beats up a bunch of mooks and saves the day" (never mind the extensive destruction that happens anyway).

Is there some commentary by the creators on whether such a moral was intended (and maybe discarded)? Or was this matter discussed by any notable reviews of the film?